# How can I upmix audio system wide from stereo to 5.1 surround?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, sound-card, 5.1

I currently have a studio subwoofer hooked up to the c/sub jack and a 2.1 speaker system in the green front LR audio jack.

**System**: Windows 10 Pro, Maximus Hero VIII motherboard with Realtek HD Audio Manager

I'd like to turn off the sub on the 2.1 system and just use the subwoofer instead for bass. I have gone into Realtek HD audio manager and switched to 5.1 mode. When I test the audio, I get the rumble from the sub and the normal sound from the 2.1 sound system.

Is there some sort of registry edit, etc. which enables stereo audio being duplicated through all channels? This way I can get clean audio through the 2.1 speakers bypass, and all the bass from the sub which has no studio monitors attached.

Comment: The only way to switch off the sub in the 2.1 would be from the 2.1 hardware itself. It's being fed 2.0 so it's doing its own crossover internally. Your question title doesn't match your actual question, btw. You're not upmixing anything.

Comment: @Tetsujin did you really read the details of the question?... What I WANT TO DO is upmix. I'm currently not doing that. The 2.1 system has the option to turn off its subwoofer. I said "I'd like to turn off the sub on the 2.1 system", implying that that's what I would do, while using the studio sub (if someone answered with a way to upmix). Currently it all works fine when I play 5.1 media content, it's just that nearly everything is 2.1.

Comment: Why did you even bother mentioning the sub on the 2.1 then, if it has no relevance to your question? You'd do a whole lot better if you plugged everything into the same set of ports - the rear set - then the Reatek CP can do fake fill to 5.1